# Electric field boundary conditions proof

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance, boundary-conditions, dielectric

Good day

I have a question regarding the boundary conditions proof:
here is my question :
in order to proof that the tangential component of the electric field  are equal in the two mediums we start from this relation
[image]

[image]

but as we can see , the electric field is different from region A to region B so how can we use this integral? my question is the same regarding the flux density ? many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields don't need to be the same. If you already knew they were the same you wouldn't need the integral.

Apply the integral over each leg of the rectangle separately. The left and right cancel out and the field is constant on the top and bottom legs (in the limit of small $\Delta w$). There's no reason it has to be the same on both legs to integrate each one separately.